# Lazy Load Instagram Blockquote Embed

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

Has anyone tried to lazy load an instagram blockquote?

Are there any libraries out there for lazy loading an instagram blockquote?

Comment: I may come back with an answer later, but so far I'm not finding much either. I just found this article for doing so with youtube content, and I am confident the technique should likely be able to be repurposed for instagram embeds: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos--cms-26743

Comment: (to clarify: just identify if the user has scrolled over the div, and then activate div replacement with generated iframe. use a generic 'instagram' logo in the meantime.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a library: https://codepen.io/kerns/pen/mPReGE

```html
      <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="710" scrolling="no" data-src="//instagram.com/p/zkOqETkZjI/embed/" width="612" class="lazyload"></iframe>
```

```js
    // Responsive LazyLoaded Intagram Embed.
    // Loads the embed, but lazyily.
    // Maintains aspect ratio of the embed across varying widths
    // Based on codepen/ryanburnette's orignal jQuery plugin
    // https://github.com/ryanburnette/responsive-instagram
    // But this is vanilla JS and...has some other features.

    window.responsiveIframes = {
        defaults: {
            width: 610,
            extraHeight: 80,
            breakpoint: 620,
            fullWidth: true, // If true, iFrame will always have a width of 100% until it reaches maxWidth
            maxWidth: 800, // Only works when fullWidth is true. Sets CSS max-width to this value.
            src: ['instagram.com'],
            lazysizes: true // Compatible with lazysizes
        },

        options: {},
        frames: [],
        initialized: false,

        init: function(param_options) {
            this.frames = [];

            if (arguments.length === 1 && typeof param_options === 'object') {
                this.options = this.helpers.extend(this.defaults, param_options);
            } else {
                this.options = this.helpers.extend(this.defaults, {});
            }

            this.initialized = true;

            // Attach listeners to resize iFrame with window.
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                window.responsiveIframes.resizeFrames();
            });
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                window.responsiveIframes.resizeFrames();
            });

        },
        resizeFrames: function() {
            if (!this.initialized) {
                this.init();
            }

            if (this.frames.length === 0) {
                this.frames = this.helpers.getIframes(this.options.src);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < this.frames.length; i++) {
                this.resizeFrame(this.frames[i]);
            }
        },
        resizeFrame: function(elem) {
            var width;
            var windowWidth = this.helpers.windowWidth();
            var newHeight;

            if (this.options.fullWidth) {
                elem.style.width = '100%';
                elem.style.maxWidth = this.options.maxWidth + 'px';
            } else {
                if (windowWidth <= this.options.breakpoint) {
                    elem.style.width = '100%';
                } else {
                    elem.style.width = this.options.width.toString(10) + 'px';
                }
            }

            width = elem.offsetWidth;

            newHeight = Math.round(width + this.options.extraHeight);
            elem.style.height = newHeight.toString(10) + 'px';
        },
        helpers: {
            windowWidth: function() {
                var docElemProp = window.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                var body = window.document.body;
                return window.document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" && docElemProp || body && body.clientWidth || docElemProp;
            },
            extend: function(obj, extObj) {
                if (arguments.length > 2) {
                    for (var a = 1; a < arguments.length; a++) {
                        this.extend2(obj, arguments[a]);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i in extObj) {
                        obj[i] = extObj[i];
                    }
                }
                return obj;
            },
            getInstagramIframes: function() {
                var matchingElements = [];
                var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

                for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
                    var src = allElements[i].getAttribute('src');
                    if (src !== null && src.indexOf('instagram.com') !== -1) {
                        matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
                    }
                }

                return matchingElements;
            },
            getIframes: function(param_src) {
                var matchingElements = [];
                var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

                for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
                    var src = allElements[i].getAttribute('src');

                    if (src === null || (typeof src === 'string' && src.length === 0)) {
                        src = allElements[i].getAttribute('data-src');
                    }

                    if (src !== null) {
                        if (Array.isArray(param_src)) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < param_src.length; j++) {
                                if (src.indexOf(param_src[j]) !== -1) {
                                    matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (src.indexOf(param_src) !== -1) {
                                matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return matchingElements;
            }
        }

    };

    // Single domain example
    // window.responsiveIframes.init({src: 'instagram.com'});

    // Multi-domains example
    // window.responsiveIframes.init({
    // src: ['instagram.com', 'youtube.com'],
    // fullWidth: true,
    // maxWidth: 900
    // });

    window.responsiveIframes.init();

    // EOF
```

```css
/* Demo Styles */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font:1.2em/1.5 'Lato', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1D1F20;
  color: #777;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: #efefef;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  b {
    color: skyblue;
  }
}

a,
a:visited {
  color: white;
}

main {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #111;
  padding:3em;
}

hr {
  margin: 2em 0;
  border-color: #333;
}

/* Instagram Embed */
iframe[data-src*="instagram.com"], iframe[src*="instagram.com"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 3em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
}
```