Instagram Script for embed infinitely refresh my Wordpress Page. How to fix it?
I embed some instagram post on my page here https://onadlaniej.pl/instagram/ and for some reason this official instagram script make my page infinietly refresh
I took whole code directly from instagram so i believe it should work properly but somehow it doesn't.
I've already identify that it is couse but his script but have no idea how to fix it. Mpoving it into header didn;t change anything, leaving only one post didn;t help.
Any idea?

Could you please share the Code you are using for this. Also we can load scripts on scroll so the performance of the page can be improved.

Due to char limitation in the comment i can't add full code however it's taken directly from instagram profile. What is interesting on mobile this issue is  doesn't exist
The script that generate this issue is this one

You can find the solution which has same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857977/lazy-load-instagram-blockquote-embed
